# Rails cron task development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

Im' trying to figure out how Whenever gem is working.

I would like to create a User instance every minute.

I put the following in my schedule.rb file :

```
set :output, "/log/cron_log.log"
set :environment, 'development'

every 1.minute do
  rake "User.create!(nni: 'TEST0',
              password: '123123',
              password_confirmation: '123123',
              nomprenom: 'user')"
end
```

Then I typed `whenever --update-crontab` and checked with `crontab -l` and get the following

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/harri/Documents/argia/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-07-10 17:19:18 +0200
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/harri/Documents/argia && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake User.create!(nni: '\''TEST0'\'', password: '\''123123'\'', password_confirmation: '\''123123'\'', nomprenom: '\''user'\'') --silent >> /log/cron_log.log 2>&1'
# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/harri/Documents/argia/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-07-10 17:19:18 +0200
```

Then I start my localhost and nothing happens, nothing in the log and it doesn't create any User instance.

Comment: Have you tried without double quote for User.create line?

Comment: @JagdishN Yes, it gives me a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how Whenever gem is working.

It works by generating a crontab file with your commands. Then OS/crond take over.

> Then I start my localhost and nothing happens, nothing in the log and it doesn't create any User instance.

Well, that's not a valid rake command you have there. Check cron logs, you'll see an error there. Did you mean to use `runner`?

Comment: Hi @Sergio Tuluntsev, no I don't know `runner`, can you tell me more please ? 
It doesn't create any log file at the Path I specified.

Comment: @MaxPuissant: "no I don't know runner, can you tell me more please " - take a look at whenever's readme.

Comment: @MaxPuissant "It doesn't create any log file at the Path I specified" - does your user have permissions to write to that location?

Comment: @MaxPuissant: how do you know? Show me.

Comment: you mean this `-rwxrwx--x  1 harri harri      0 juil. 10 17:10 cron_log.log` ?

Comment: @MaxPuissant: yes, and the command itself, just to be sure. Also, output says "harri", but you're "Max". :)

Comment: I just used the command `ls -la` in my log folder. Max is my nickname

Comment: @MaxPuissant: which "my log folder" is that exactly, is what I'm asking. Is it really a top level folder? If so, it would be.... unusual. Normally people don't do that and instead keep logs in respective project folders.

Comment: The log folder path is `my_project/log`

Comment: @MaxPuissant yeah, that's what I thought, 13 hours ago. Your cron task attemps to write to somewhere else (and likely doesn't have permissions to do that)

Comment: It is not enough to set output like that : `set :output, "/log/cron_log.log" ` ?

Comment: @MaxPuissant: read up on the difference between absolute and relative paths.

Comment: ookay thanks..  Now I see error in my log file : `/bin/bash: bundle: command not found`.
How can I create a user instance with a rake command ?

Comment: @MaxPuissant: out of scope of the question.

Comment: not really : `I would like to create a User instance every minute. ` I just forgot to precise that I want to do it with a rake command

Comment: @MaxPuissant: in this case, create a rake task which does that and simply reference it. You can't just throw random ruby code at `rake` command line tool. And how to create rake tasks _is_ out of scope. :)

Comment: @MaxPuissant: you did find and read whenever's readme, right?

Comment: Yes sure, but did not found rake command examples to manipulate model instances.

Comment: @MaxPuissant: that's because for running ad-hoc snippets of ruby they use another thing. And if you absolutely _need_ to run your code as a rake task (for whatever reason), you're supposed to have it already or know how to make it.

Comment: No I don't absolutely need to run it as a rake task, all I need is just to create a new instance of my model every minute, or hour, or day :)